# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded Error in Spartacus

Tags: upgrade, spartacus-storefront, storefront

We have updated the Spartacus version 4.1.0 to 5.0.0.
We are calling the `getSelectedPaymentTypeState()` method in the payment type screen. But i am getting the following error.

```
node_modules_spartacus_checkout_fesm2020_spartacus-checkout-base_mjs.js:2 
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75:26)
    at Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55:18)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75:26)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55:18)
    at FilterSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75:26)
    at FilterSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyError (innerSubscribe.js:45:26)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._error (innerSubscribe.js:13:21)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55:18)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyError (innerSubscribe.js:45:26)
```

Comment: I am getting the same error with upgrade. Did you find any solution for this?